# Book about a girl travelling to the center of a desert just to find out she herself is part alien

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember this book I read years ago but only some details. I remember the premise was that the moon had stopped or was broken up. I remember specifically a city being destroyed. I think the story mainly followed a girl travelling through to try to get to the center of a desert just to find out she herself is part alien or something like that. it felt like a space western, but it may have just had scenes that took place in the desert

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: The Darkangel trilogy by Meredith Pierce? Over the story arc, we learn that it's set on a terraformed moon. In the first book, a girl has to travel through a desert. At the end of the third book, she discovers that she was mostly destroyed in an explosion, and re-built using her brain and (I think) her eyes. She is now some sort of immortal cyborg.